# C# Prohibiting user typing Words instead of numbers

Tags: c#, calculator

Having some problems with my Console Calculator
I want to prohibit user inputing a words instead of numbers.
I wrote this code and its converting words to zero but i want user to type a number instead of words. And if user still typing words program should ask user to type number.

internal class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)

```
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("------Calculator------");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
        do
        {

            double num1 = 0;
            double num2 = 0;
            double result = 0;
            bool result0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number one: ");
          
            try
            {
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1);
                if ()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number!\nType another number:");
                    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }

            }
             catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
                
            
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number two: ");

            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`double.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0) inside a `if` condition with [negation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-).

If you want to force user to show `"Incorrect number!\nType another number:"` message till the user enters correct integer, use `while()` loop instead of `if()` condition.

```
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1))
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number!\nType another number:");
```

Why we should use `double.TryParse()` inside `if` condition?

- `double.TryParse()`, parse string value to double and return true if conversion succeeded or not.
- In your case, if user enters word instead of number then conversion will fail and use of `!(negation)` will iterate the loop again.